# how to generate a deadlock scenario in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I've been stuck on a Lab question for the last four hours because I generally don't understand what it wants, even with extensive research and flipping through endless slides. EDIT the prologue in question is a dbcreate.sql which creates a series of tables, and then a dbload.sql which inserts values into given tables.

The given question is

> Implement in PL/SQL the database transactions that operate on the sample database created in Prologue step and such that their concurrent processing leads to dadeadlock situation. Save the transactions in SQL scripts solution1-1.sql and solution1-2.sql

I feel someone on this site could explain this in a way I  can understand! Thank you for your help

EDIT theres a second part to this question

> Simulate a concurrent processing of the transaction such that it will lead to a deadlock.
>   To simulate a concurrent processing of the database transactions use a PL/SQL procedure
>   SLEEP from the standard PL/SQL package DBMS_LOCK. By "simulation of concurrent
>   execution" we mean that the first transaction does a bit of work, then it is delayed for a
>   certain period of time and in the same period of time another transaction is processed.
>   Finally, after a delay the first transaction completes its job.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a [deadlock](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks) situation to demonstrate that you understand what it is. You will need to have two sessions amending the same row in such a way that they block each other and cause an ORA-00060 error. If that is the case then your question title should probably mention deadlocks. I don't know how PL/SQL comes into this or what kind of scripts are expected though.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson so when you say two sessions do you mean two SQL scripts that amend the same row?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson ive updated my question aslo as theres a 2nd part

Comment: I mean two connections. If I start SQL\*Plus and log in, that's one session. Your question is about concurrent processing causing deadlocks, which means more than one connected user working on the same data at the same time.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson alright thankyou for clearing that up for me. Also what does it mean by a transaction?

Comment: A transaction consists of one or more inserts, updates or deletes etc terminated by a commit or rollback. Your course should probably have covered this before setting the deadlock task. Are you clear about what a deadlock is?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson two sessions of different users amending the same row

Comment: That's not enough for a deadlock, it's just a blocking lock. The second session will wait for the first one to commit or roll back. Have another read of the article I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way (untested code):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE doUpd ( id1 IN NUMBER, id2 IN NUMBER ) IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE tableA set colA = 'upd1' where id = id1;
   dbms_lock.sleep (20);
   UPDATE tableA set colA = 'upd2' where id = id2;
END;
/
```

Then run in session 1:

```
execute doUpd( 21, 12 );
```

Immediate in session 2:

```
execute doUpd( 12, 21 );
```

What we're doing is updating 2 rows of but is a different order.
We would hope that the time between between the updates would be small enough not avoid a deadlock. But if we want to simulate a deadlock, we need add a delay so that we can fire off the updates in another session.

In the example above, session 1 will update the rows with id = 21 , then wait for 20 seconds, then update the row with id 12.

Session 2 will update the rows with id = 12 , then wait for 20 seconds, then update the row with id 21. If session 2 starts whilst session 1 is 'sleeping' we should get a deadlock.

In time order, provided you are quick with starting the session 2 job, you should be aiming for this:

Session 1: `UPDATE tableA set colA = 'upd1' where id = 21;`

Session 1: `sleep 20`

Session 2: `UPDATE tableA set colA = 'upd1' where id = 12;`

Session 2: `sleep 20`

Session 1: `UPDATE tableA set colA = 'upd2' where id = 12;` -- blocked until session 2 commit/rollback

Session 2: `UPDATE tableA set colA = 'upd2' where id = 21;` -- blocked until session 1 commit/rollback

Session 1 and 2 are now deadlocked.

Comment: Worth mentioning that DBMS_LOCK is unavailable by default, and we need a DBA to grant execute privilege to us. As the OP's assignment explicitly mentions the package we would expect this wrinkle to have been handled for them but other Seekers might stumble on it.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - well I thought I'd leave it to you to point that fact out :D

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question you can use also this example without `DBMS_LOCK` package:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (c INTEGER, v INTEGER);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2, 10);
COMMIT;
```

1. Open session 1
2. Open session 2
3. In session 1 execute `update t1 set v = v + 10 where c = 1;`
4. In session 2 execute `update t1 set v = v + 10 where c = 2;`
5. In session 1 execute `update t1 set v = v + 10 where c = 2;`
6. In session 2 execute `update t1 set v = v + 10 where c = 1;`
7. Session 1 raises an `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`

Comment: No deadlock occured by above statement, there should be begin transaction.

Comment: @Dineshvishe: I get an "ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource" error with the above sequence as expected; maybe you have AUTOCOMMIT ON?